# Search for TimeStamp in multiple log files using time range but I have huge data. So, How can I extract the logs very quickly?

Tags: database

I want to access the old log files to debug but I have very huge data (300TB) and each log file is of 19GB. Using Time range, I have to extract the logs using Timestamp. So, How can I extract the logs very quickly and even I have to print it to console?

Each log file is a single line text starting with Time stamp.

```
2020-01-31T20:12:37.1234Z, Some Field, Other Field, And so on
2020-01-31T20:12:37.1235Z, Some Field, Other Field, And so on
2020-01-31T20:12:37.1236Z, Some Field, Other Field, And so on
2020-01-31T20:12:37.1237Z, Some Field, Other Field, And so on
```

Comment: It depends on the logfiles format and if it's very consistant and each line start with the timestamp. I that case I would write a python script that open the file, read the start line and end line see if the timestamp are in the search range, if this is the case seek in the middle, and read the line there, if it's before consider the middle as the start, if it's after consider it the end and repeat you'll finally find the range and extract the information you need.

Comment: please add sample rows from the log file

Comment: I edited the post, please check the format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell to get the lines containing a specific timestamp at the start of the line. If you want to export the results to csv, you can leverage Export-CSV option. Otherwise, the output will be sent to console.

```bsh
set-location "LogFolder" 
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | `
Select-String  -Pattern "^Timestamp" | `
Select path, LineNumber, Line `
#| Export-Csv C:\OutputFolder\TimestampPresence_InLog.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: If we have multiple files, then it is able to access quickly?

Comment: @Krishnakanth, It is quick only. But, I think UNIX tools like `grep`, `sed` will be very fast.